# Repair the Windows recovery partition/fix errors preventing WinRE from enabling

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, windows-re

I've performed the Windows 10 reset process successfully, however now Windows RE is disabled and I can not figure out how to fix that. I now have two recovery partitions, a 523MB and 510MB one, and I've lost the "Windows Recovery Environment" BCD boot entry:

```
Windows Recovery Environment (Windows RE) and system reset configuration
Information:

    Windows RE status:         Disabled
    Windows RE location:
    Boot Configuration Data (BCD) identifier: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
    Recovery image location:
    Recovery image index:      0
    Custom image location:
    Custom image index:        0

REAGENTC.EXE: Operation Successful.
```

The first WinRE partition appears to be incomplete as there are no other files in the folder where the `Winre.wim` is located, and attempting to manually specify the second partition appears to be okay for use, reporting success:

```
reagentc /setreimage /path Y:\Recovery\WindowsRE\Winre.wim
```

- Subsequent `reagentc /enable` reports the same and I've tried to set the first partition to a basic data partition, ensuring the second has the correct partition type ID as well:

  ```
  REAGENTC.EXE: Unable to update Boot Configuration Data
  ```

How do I fix this?

- **Log:**

  ```
  [ReAgentc.exe] -----Executing command line: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\ReAgentc.exe" /enable-----
  [ReAgentc.exe] ------------------------------------------------------

  [ReAgentc.exe] Enter WinRECheckGuid
  [ReAgentc.exe] Parameter: TargetOsGuid: : NULL
  [ReAgentc.exe] Exit WinRECheckGuid return error code: 0x0
  [ReAgentc.exe] Enter WinReInstall
  [ReAgentc.exe] Parameter: ReInstallBecauseOfBitlocker: 0

  [ReAgentc.exe] --Install on target OS step 1: collect info like partition list, loading reagent.xml, source winre.wim and partition
  [ReAgentc.exe] Enumerate and log all fixed partitions:

  [ReAgentc.exe] --Partition info--
  [ReAgentc.exe] VolumeName: \\?\Volume{48686080-7948-482c-bd6e-5897c8c50e49}, PartitionName: \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk4\partition2
  [ReAgentc.exe] Partition number: 2, offset: 549453824, free space: 252575744, total space: 300335104
  [ReAgentc.exe] DiskNumber:4, DiskSignature:0, NTFS:0, Mbr:0, Active:0, Boot:0, BitlockerEnabled:0
  [ReAgentc.exe] GPT partition GUID:: {C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B}
  [ReAgentc.exe] DiskId: {10F90CB2-5858-9090-8081-828310111213}

  [ReAgentc.exe] --Partition info--
  [ReAgentc.exe] VolumeName: \\?\Volume{0000008d-83e0-2b05-ff33-d7011a010000}, PartitionName: \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk6\partition2
  [ReAgentc.exe] Partition number: 2, offset: 135269888, free space: 267675643904, total space: 1000068431872
  [ReAgentc.exe] DiskNumber:6, DiskSignature:0, NTFS:1, Mbr:0, Active:0, Boot:0, BitlockerEnabled:0
  [ReAgentc.exe] GPT partition GUID:: {EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7}
  [ReAgentc.exe] DiskId: {55F33A00-6786-03AE-80CE-7C95E199EB00}

  [ReAgentc.exe] --Partition info--
  [ReAgentc.exe] VolumeName: \\?\Volume{1a4b4c45-1b8e-11ee-a71b-9873aff86160}, PartitionName: \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk4\partition8
  [ReAgentc.exe] Partition number: 8, offset: 448003047424, free space: 86556672, total space: 534769664
  [ReAgentc.exe] DiskNumber:4, DiskSignature:0, NTFS:1, Mbr:0, Active:0, Boot:0, BitlockerEnabled:0
  [ReAgentc.exe] GPT partition GUID:: {DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC}
  [ReAgentc.exe] DiskId: {10F90CB2-5858-9090-8081-828310111213}

  [ReAgentc.exe] --Partition info--
  [ReAgentc.exe] VolumeName: \\?\Volume{1a4b4c44-1b8e-11ee-a71b-9873aff86160}, PartitionName: \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk4\partition7
  [ReAgentc.exe] Partition number: 7, offset: 447688474624, free space: 310353920, total space: 310378496
  [ReAgentc.exe] DiskNumber:4, DiskSignature:0, NTFS:0, Mbr:0, Active:0, Boot:0, BitlockerEnabled:0
  [ReAgentc.exe] GPT partition GUID:: {EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7}
  [ReAgentc.exe] DiskId: {10F90CB2-5858-9090-8081-828310111213}

  [ReAgentc.exe] --Partition info--
  [ReAgentc.exe] VolumeName: \\?\Volume{7db2481d-bd54-11ec-850e-9db0c526c3cb}, PartitionName: \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk4\partition6
  [ReAgentc.exe] Partition number: 6, offset: 143152775168, free space: 12039639040, total space: 304535695360
  [ReAgentc.exe] DiskNumber:4, DiskSignature:0, NTFS:1, Mbr:0, Active:0, Boot:0, BitlockerEnabled:0
  [ReAgentc.exe] GPT partition GUID:: {EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7}
  [ReAgentc.exe] DiskId: {10F90CB2-5858-9090-8081-828310111213}

  [ReAgentc.exe] --Partition info--
  [ReAgentc.exe] VolumeName: \\?\Volume{7db24819-bd54-11ec-850e-9db0c526c3cb}, PartitionName: \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk4\partition5
  [ReAgentc.exe] Partition number: 5, offset: 78724242944, free space: 0, total space: 0
  [ReAgentc.exe] DiskNumber:4, DiskSignature:0, NTFS:0, Mbr:0, Active:0, Boot:0, BitlockerEnabled:0
  [ReAgentc.exe] GPT partition GUID:: {EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7}
  [ReAgentc.exe] DiskId: {10F90CB2-5858-9090-8081-828310111213}

  [ReAgentc.exe] --Partition info--
  [ReAgentc.exe] VolumeName: \\?\Volume{7db24811-bd54-11ec-850e-9db0c526c3cb}, PartitionName: \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk4\partition4
  [ReAgentc.exe] Partition number: 4, offset: 984612864, free space: 16934952960, total space: 77739323392
  [ReAgentc.exe] DiskNumber:4, DiskSignature:0, NTFS:1, Mbr:0, Active:0, Boot:1, BitlockerEnabled:0
  [ReAgentc.exe] GPT partition GUID:: {EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7}
  [ReAgentc.exe] DiskId: {10F90CB2-5858-9090-8081-828310111213}

  [ReAgentc.exe] --Partition info--
  [ReAgentc.exe] VolumeName: \\?\Volume{bf0b9e10-ad65-01d9-08cb-85dfb2d6ec00}, PartitionName: \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk4\partition1
  [ReAgentc.exe] Partition number: 1, offset: 1048576, free space: 90918912, total space: 548401152
  [ReAgentc.exe] DiskNumber:4, DiskSignature:0, NTFS:1, Mbr:0, Active:0, Boot:0, BitlockerEnabled:0
  [ReAgentc.exe] GPT partition GUID:: {EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7}
  [ReAgentc.exe] DiskId: {10F90CB2-5858-9090-8081-828310111213}

  [ReAgentc.exe] --Partition info--
  [ReAgentc.exe] VolumeName: \\?\Volume{21690322-195b-4fc7-93b9-cd3e54fc8ad1}, PartitionName: \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk3\partition2
  [ReAgentc.exe] Partition number: 2, offset: 16777216, free space: 1506555363328, total space: 3000574668800
  [ReAgentc.exe] DiskNumber:3, DiskSignature:0, NTFS:1, Mbr:0, Active:0, Boot:0, BitlockerEnabled:0
  [ReAgentc.exe] GPT partition GUID:: {EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7}
  [ReAgentc.exe] DiskId: {7634C4F7-E13C-4425-B904-2C24D8BF80BE}

  [ReAgentc.exe] --Partition info--
  [ReAgentc.exe] VolumeName: \\?\Volume{27557c6f-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}, PartitionName: \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk2\partition1
  [ReAgentc.exe] Partition number: 1, offset: 1048576, free space: 58231140352, total space: 500104687616
  [ReAgentc.exe] DiskNumber:2, DiskSignature:659913839, NTFS:1, Mbr:1, Active:0, Boot:0, BitlockerEnabled:0
  [ReAgentc.exe] MBR partition id: 0x7
  [ReAgentc.exe] DiskId: {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

  [ReAgentc.exe] --Partition info--
  [ReAgentc.exe] VolumeName: \\?\Volume{3b8a26a2-cbd5-4549-a6f2-3800e39e3dbe}, PartitionName: \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk1\partition1
  [ReAgentc.exe] Partition number: 1, offset: 32768, free space: 81808039936, total space: 500105728000
  [ReAgentc.exe] DiskNumber:1, DiskSignature:0, NTFS:1, Mbr:0, Active:0, Boot:0, BitlockerEnabled:0
  [ReAgentc.exe] GPT partition GUID:: {EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7}
  [ReAgentc.exe] DiskId: {5DE2D4BA-5015-4342-BB00-018B62B6827C}

  [ReAgentc.exe] --Partition info--
  [ReAgentc.exe] VolumeName: \\?\Volume{0f9a8d0c-13f8-48c8-9c9a-3625d0ee6ca3}, PartitionName: \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk0\partition3
  [ReAgentc.exe] Partition number: 3, offset: 64548241408, free space: 121528864768, total space: 382600212480
  [ReAgentc.exe] DiskNumber:0, DiskSignature:0, NTFS:1, Mbr:0, Active:0, Boot:0, BitlockerEnabled:0
  [ReAgentc.exe] GPT partition GUID:: {EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7}
  [ReAgentc.exe] DiskId: {55DE90FF-D869-4801-BDBE-927EAD1B8F16}

  [ReAgentc.exe] --Partition info--
  [ReAgentc.exe] VolumeName: \\?\Volume{781e2292-d9cb-43f5-a940-1614a736b33e}, PartitionName: \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk0\partition2
  [ReAgentc.exe] Partition number: 2, offset: 122683392, free space: 16323956736, total space: 64424611840
  [ReAgentc.exe] DiskNumber:0, DiskSignature:0, NTFS:1, Mbr:0, Active:0, Boot:0, BitlockerEnabled:0
  [ReAgentc.exe] GPT partition GUID:: {EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7}
  [ReAgentc.exe] DiskId: {55DE90FF-D869-4801-BDBE-927EAD1B8F16}

  [ReAgentc.exe] Get downlevel ReAgent config
  [ReAgentc.exe]  Downlevel config file path: \Recovery\ReAgentOld.xml
  [ReAgentc.exe]  Checking for downlevel WinRE installation.

  [ReAgentc.exe] read xml file (\Recovery\ReAgentOld.xml) failed: 0x3
  [ReAgentc.exe] ReAgentXMLParser::ParseConfigFile failed to read config xml file (0x3) in file base\diagnosis\srt\reagent2\reinfo\parser_2.0.cpp line 784
  [ReAgentc.exe] ReAgentXMLParser::ParseConfigFile (xml file: \Recovery\ReAgentOld.xml) returning 0x3
  [ReAgentc.exe] ReAgentConfig::ParseConfigFile  returned with 0x3

  [ReAgentc.exe] ReAgentConfig::Init failed to init reagent xml parser (0x3) in file base\diagnosis\srt\reagent2\reinfo\parser_2.0.cpp line 1921
  [ReAgentc.exe]  Ignore the error 3 in function GetDownlevelReAgentConfig

  [ReAgentc.exe] First round search
  [ReAgentc.exe] Get ReAgent config
  [ReAgentc.exe] GetReAgentConfig Config file path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\Recovery\ReAgent.xml
  [ReAgentc.exe] CheckRegKey test hook (SystemSetupInProgress) present and disabled
  [ReAgentc.exe] Update enhanced config info is enabled.
  [ReAgentc.exe] BcdOpenObject(WinRE) failed: 0xc0000034
  [ReAgentc.exe] winreGetWinReGuid returning 0X2
  [ReAgentc.exe] ReAgentConfig::ReadBcdAndUpdateEnhancedConfigInfo WinRE disabled, WinRE Guid could not be determined  (0x2)

  [ReAgentc.exe] --Install on target OS step 2: detect and fix if there is any issue for winre settings
  [ReAgentc.exe] DetectAndFixWinReIssues (WinRE)WinRE is already installed, setting BCD entry (winre location \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk4\partition1\Recovery\WindowsRE)
  [ReAgentc.exe] BcdOpenObject(WinRE) failed: 0xc0000034
  [ReAgentc.exe] winreGetWinReGuid returning 0X2
  [ReAgentc.exe] DetectAndFixWinReIssues Failed to get WinRE GUID.
  [ReAgentc.exe] DetectAndFixWinReIssues Will fix the BCD entry.
  [ReAgentc.exe] BcdOpenObject(WinRE) failed: 0xc0000034
  [ReAgentc.exe] winreGetWinReGuid returning 0X2
  [ReAgentc.exe] NOTE: WILL RETRY. We have to uninstall WinRE and retry because WinRE is installed but its BCD entry is not present.
  [ReAgentc.exe] DetectAndFixWinReIssues Copying Winre.wim from \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk4\partition1\Recovery\WindowsRE to staging location
  [ReAgentc.exe] boot.sdi is not available under \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk4\partition1\Recovery\WindowsRE
  [ReAgentc.exe] winreCopyWIMBack moved WIM file from \\?\GLOBALROOT\device\harddisk4\partition1\Recovery\WindowsRE to  successfully!

  [ReAgentc.exe] DetectAndFixWinReIssues we should retry because winre installation was changed.
  [ReAgentc.exe] failed to detect and fix winre issues, error:0x2
  [ReAgentc.exe] Exit WinReInstall return value: 0, last error: 0x2
  [ReAgentc.exe] failed to install winre: : 0x2

  [ReAgentc.exe] ------------------------------------------------------
  [ReAgentc.exe] -----Exiting command line: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\ReAgentc.exe" /enable, Error: 2-----
  ```
- **Windows Boot Manager:**

  ```
  Windows Boot Manager
  --------------------
  identifier              {9dea862c-5cdd-4e70-acc1-f32b344d4795}
  device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
  path                    \EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI
  description             Windows Boot Manager
  locale                  en-US
  inherit                 {7ea2e1ac-2e61-4728-aaa3-896d9d0a9f0e}
  default                 {225a5d6d-1bc8-11ee-a27b-ad72d621c039}
  resumeobject            {225a5d6c-1bc8-11ee-a27b-ad72d621c039}
  displayorder            {225a5d6d-1bc8-11ee-a27b-ad72d621c039}
  toolsdisplayorder       {b2721d73-1db4-4c62-bf78-c548a880142d}
  timeout                 30
  displaybootmenu         Yes
  ```
- **Windows Boot Loader:**

  ```
  Windows Boot Loader
  -------------------
  identifier              {225a5d6d-1bc8-11ee-a27b-ad72d621c039}
  device                  partition=C:
  path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi
  description             Windows 10
  locale                  en-US
  inherit                 {6efb52bf-1766-41db-a6b3-0ee5eff72bd7}
  recoverysequence        {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
  displaymessageoverride  Recovery
  recoveryenabled         Yes
  isolatedcontext         Yes
  allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
  osdevice                partition=C:
  systemroot              \WINDOWS
  resumeobject            {225a5d6c-1bc8-11ee-a27b-ad72d621c039}
  nx                      OptIn
  bootmenupolicy          Standard
  hypervisorlaunchtype    Auto

  Resume from Hibernate
  ---------------------
  identifier              {225a5d6c-1bc8-11ee-a27b-ad72d621c039}
  device                  partition=C:
  path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winresume.efi
  description             Windows Resume Application
  locale                  en-US
  inherit                 {1afa9c49-16ab-4a5c-901b-212802da9460}
  recoverysequence        {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
  recoveryenabled         Yes
  isolatedcontext         Yes
  allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
  filedevice              partition=C:
  filepath                \hiberfil.sys
  bootmenupolicy          Standard
  debugoptionenabled      No

  Windows Memory Tester
  ---------------------
  identifier              {b2721d73-1db4-4c62-bf78-c548a880142d}
  device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
  path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\memtest.efi
  description             Windows Memory Diagnostic
  locale                  en-US
  inherit                 {7ea2e1ac-2e61-4728-aaa3-896d9d0a9f0e}
  badmemoryaccess         Yes

  EMS Settings
  ------------
  identifier              {0ce4991b-e6b3-4b16-b23c-5e0d9250e5d9}
  bootems                 No

  Debugger Settings
  -----------------
  identifier              {4636856e-540f-4170-a130-a84776f4c654}
  debugtype               Local

  RAM Defects
  -----------
  identifier              {5189b25c-5558-4bf2-bca4-289b11bd29e2}

  Global Settings
  ---------------
  identifier              {7ea2e1ac-2e61-4728-aaa3-896d9d0a9f0e}
  inherit                 {4636856e-540f-4170-a130-a84776f4c654}
                          {0ce4991b-e6b3-4b16-b23c-5e0d9250e5d9}
                          {5189b25c-5558-4bf2-bca4-289b11bd29e2}

  Boot Loader Settings
  --------------------
  identifier              {6efb52bf-1766-41db-a6b3-0ee5eff72bd7}
  inherit                 {7ea2e1ac-2e61-4728-aaa3-896d9d0a9f0e}
                          {7ff607e0-4395-11db-b0de-0800200c9a66}

  Hypervisor Settings
  -------------------
  identifier              {7ff607e0-4395-11db-b0de-0800200c9a66}
  hypervisordebugtype     Serial
  hypervisordebugport     1
  hypervisorbaudrate      115200

  Resume Loader Settings
  ----------------------
  identifier              {1afa9c49-16ab-4a5c-901b-212802da9460}
  inherit                 {7ea2e1ac-2e61-4728-aaa3-896d9d0a9f0e}
  ```
- **Firmware Boot Manager**

  ```
  Firmware Boot Manager
  ---------------------
  identifier              {a5a30fa2-3d06-4e9f-b5f4-a01df9d1fcba}
  displayorder            {9dea862c-5cdd-4e70-acc1-f32b344d4795}
                          {9167a6e4-1a80-11ee-b2db-709cd13cf14e}
                          {fe4b36f8-1af6-11ee-b2dc-806e6f6e6963}
                          {11fd2d77-1b03-11ee-b2de-806e6f6e6963}
                          {9167a6e5-1a80-11ee-b2db-709cd13cf14e}
                          {9167a6e6-1a80-11ee-b2db-709cd13cf14e}
                          {a8f97dc3-291a-11ee-bea1-806e6f6e6963}
                          {a8f97dc4-291a-11ee-bea1-806e6f6e6963}
                          {a8f97dc5-291a-11ee-bea1-806e6f6e6963}
  timeout                 1
  ```
- **Firmware Application:**

  ```
  Firmware Application (101fffff)
  -------------------------------
  identifier              {11fd2d77-1b03-11ee-b2de-806e6f6e6963}
  device                  unknown
  description             UEFI: SanDisk, Partition 2

  Firmware Application (101fffff)
  -------------------------------
  identifier              {9167a6e2-1a80-11ee-b2db-709cd13cf14e}
  device                  partition=M:
  description             UEFI: Generic Mass-Storage 1.11, Partition 1

  Firmware Application (101fffff)
  -------------------------------
  identifier              {9167a6e3-1a80-11ee-b2db-709cd13cf14e}
  description             UEFI: General UDisk 5.00, Partition 1

  Firmware Application (101fffff)
  -------------------------------
  identifier              {9167a6e4-1a80-11ee-b2db-709cd13cf14e}
  device                  partition=M:
  description             UEFI: Generic Mass-Storage 1.11, Partition 1

  Firmware Application (101fffff)
  -------------------------------
  identifier              {9167a6e5-1a80-11ee-b2db-709cd13cf14e}
  description             UEFI: PXE IPv4 Intel(R) Ethernet Controller (2) I225-V

  Firmware Application (101fffff)
  -------------------------------
  identifier              {9167a6e6-1a80-11ee-b2db-709cd13cf14e}
  description             UEFI: PXE IPv6 Intel(R) Ethernet Controller (2) I225-V

  Firmware Application (101fffff)
  -------------------------------
  identifier              {a8f97dc3-291a-11ee-bea1-806e6f6e6963}
  description             UEFI:CD/DVD Drive

  Firmware Application (101fffff)
  -------------------------------
  identifier              {a8f97dc4-291a-11ee-bea1-806e6f6e6963}
  description             UEFI:Removable Device

  Firmware Application (101fffff)
  -------------------------------
  identifier              {a8f97dc5-291a-11ee-bea1-806e6f6e6963}
  description             UEFI:Network Device

  Firmware Application (101fffff)
  -------------------------------
  identifier              {fe4b36f8-1af6-11ee-b2dc-806e6f6e6963}
  device                  unknown
  path                    \EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI
  description             UEFI: SanDisk, Partition 1
  ```

Comment: @JW0914: that's wrong, previously the OS did have a boot entry dedicated to the WinRE system. Now I can't enable it because it explicitly tells me that it is unable to update BCD, so I'm unsure how does your comment reconciles with my experience.

Comment: I didn't add anything to the BCD store before I reset the OS. It was a fresh install, however, there was a hardware failure that had corrupted the OS shortly after so I resorted to resetting it. It wasn't dual-boot too, because I had actually formatted pretty much every drive anew beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long, I've finally resolved the issue. I've had to delete the `ReAgent.xml` file, then I was able to use `ReAgentC`'s commands to specify the location of the recovery image w/o issues and, subsequently, enable WinRE. It also, contrarily to what @JW0914 said, created/updated BCD entries for WinRE.